# Is this Cinnamon Panel item also available in Xfce? (or alternative)

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, cinnamon, xfce-panel

I'm still wondering which distro to use. So far I've tried Linux Mint 17 and I liked that, but now I'm onto Xubuntu.

In Mint (with Cinnamon) there was a really nifty (and popular) panel item called:

[Window List with App Grouping](http://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/applets/view/16)

[image: Window List with App Grouping]

It sort of resembles the MS Windows 7 taskbar ( as I left that for Linux :) ), which makes my taskbar less cluttering when I have ±1000 things opened.

The main things I like about it:

- Grouping windows
- Middle-mouse-button opens new window/instance of program
- Mouse-over shows windows

Is there anything for Xfce that does the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is old, but check out DockBarX, which is available for Xfce.  Here's some more details: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/03/dockbarx-available-as-xfce-panel-plugin.html

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Askubuntu! Thanks for you answer, but can you please include the information in your answer, instead of linking to a post. This is to make sure the information stays available on Askubuntu, even if the website you link to would be down. Thanks!